# PouchDB/CouchDB usage/schema for user data

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I'm using PouchDB + CouchDB to store and sync data in an angular app currently in development. Data is stored per user and contains things such as user authorities/settings, recently viewed content and cart items.

Currently, I have a single CouchDB database that contains a doc for each user. While this structure works well for quickly retrieving user-specific data, it's logically flawed because all user docs are synced to any device that accesses the app. In other words, I ultimately only need the currently logged in user's data to sync.

So, my question is, should I create a Couch database for each user instead of using a single database with a doc for each user? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried setting a pull filter?

Comment: @MichaelPickett No I haven't, can you point me to an example or docs? Is a pull filter accomplished with design doc queries?

Comment: Heres something I found that may help https://pouchdb.com/2015/04/05/filtered-replication.html

Comment: @MichaelPickett Damn...how did I not find that. That looks to be a very helpful article. Just in the first few lines he mentions, "There's no shame in creating a DB per user or DB per role!". I feel better already ;) Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) plugin you'll see that you can store metadata for a user in the _user database. That might be all you need.

Comment: That may work for minimal user meta but in situations where you are dealing with users' saved carts, location data, transaction history, app settings, etc. you will need  multiple docs if not multiple databases. I ended up using a single doc for each user and used filters to selectively sync only the logged in user data to their device.

Comment: The "DB per user" is a standard practice for CouchDB so storing things like "cart" data in a user's database makes sense because that's not "user" meta data. That's just data that should be stored in the user's database. 

The "_user" database is meant to provide built-in functionality for authenticating users and storing "meta data" like their name, address, etc. It is not intended to be used for storing user data.